# How to create a Child before associating it to its Parent in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, parent-child, nested-form-for, accepts-nested-attributes

I have **Categories (Parents)** within which are listed **Products (Children)**.

I want to be able to **create a new Product directly from the navbar, anywhere in the app** and then, during the creation, assign it to a Category.

However, I get the present error:

```
NoMethodError in Products#new
Showing /Users/istvanlazar/Mobily/app/views/products/new.html.erb where line #9 raised:

undefined method `products_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007febaa5aec98>:0x00007febae0f9e38>
Did you mean?  product_show_path 

## product_show_path is a custom controller that has nothing to do with this one, 
enabling show and clean redirection from newest_products index bypassing categories nesting.

Extracted source (around line #9):
9  <%= form_for [@product] do |f| %>
10   <div class="form-styling">
11     <div>
12       <%= f.label :name %>
```

My App works as such:

**Models**

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products, inverse_of: :category
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products

  validates :name, presence: true
end


class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  belongs_to :category, inverse_of: :products

  validates :category, presence: true
end
```

**Routes**

```
get 'products/new', to: 'products#new', as: 'new_product'

resources :categories, only: [:index, :show, :new, :edit] do
  resources :products, only: [:index, :show, :edit]
  # resources :products, only: [:index, :show, :new, :edit]
end
```

**Controllers**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_category, except: :new

  def index
    @products = Product.all
    @products = policy_scope(@category.products).order(created_at: :desc)
  end

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new
    @product.user = current_user
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    @product.user = current_user
    if @product.save!
      redirect_to category_product_path(@category, @product), notice: "Product has been successfully added to our database"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def set_category
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
  end

  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, :price, :description, :category_id, :user, :id)
  end
end


class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @categories = Category.all    
  end

  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    # Non-existant created in seeds.rb
  end

  def create
    # idem
  end

  def edit
    # idem
  end

  def update
    # idem
  end

  def destroy
    # idem
  end

  private

  def category_params
    params.require(:category).permit(:name, :id)
  end
end
```

**Views**

```
# In shared/navbar.html.erb:

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Some Link</li>
    <li>Another Link</li>
    <li><%= link_to "Create", new_product_path %></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

# In products/new.html.erb:

<%= form_for [@product] do |f| %>
    <div class="form-styling">
      <div>
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, required: true, placeholder: "Enter product name" %>

        <%= f.label :price %>
        <%= f.number_field :price, required: true %>
      </div>
      <div>
        <%= f.label :description %>
        <%= f.text_field :description %>
      </div>
      <div>
        <%= f.label :category %>
        <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.order(:name), :id, :name, {prompt: 'Select a Category'}, required: true %>
      </div>
      <div>
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Do you have any idea of where it went wrong? Or is it **impossible to Create a Child before assigning it to a Parent**..?

Thanks in advance.

Best,
Ist

Comment: where are you calling products_path (the error that is thrown?)

Comment: Litterally nowhere... It seems that form_for does it automatically

Comment: Searching 232 files for "products_path" (whole word)

0 matches

Comment: is @product being set correctly? and also why the array in form_for [@product] ?

Comment: @product should be Product.new , set somewhere in your controller new action

Comment: Yeah, `products_path` is being called by the `form_for [@product]`, as the form is trying to figure out where to POST to (i.e. the `action` attribute of the form tag). By default it wants to POST to `/products`, but there is no such path with the way your routes are set up. The only path for Product creation is `/categories/:category_id/product`. Try running `rake routes` in your terminal to see more about which paths are generated by your `routes.rb` file.

Comment: Correction, it looks like you don't actually currently have any routes set up for Product creation. You'll definitely need to set one of those up first, either nested under `/categories` or at the top level.

Comment: the array [@product] in form_for used to be [@category, @product], but the result is the same with (@product)

Comment: I have this route created: get 'products/new', to: 'products#new', as: 'new_product'

Comment: `new` routes are not the same as `create` routes. `new` is a GET route to show the form for creation, `create` is a POST route for taking in data and actually creating the resource. Try this: add the `[@category, @product]` back to the `form_for`, and then add `:create` to the `:only` array for the product resources nested under categories in your routes file, e.g. `resources :products, only: [:index, :show, :create, :edit]`

Comment: should I create: get 'categories/products/new', to: 'products#new', as: 'new_product'? As I want to be able to assign the category only on product creation (however, I recall trying it but it sent some error)

Comment: I've done so, and it still bring the same error ```` undefined method `products_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007fcdc59bd8a0>:0x00007fcdc627ed18>````

Comment: I've restarted my server too

Comment: No, because you already have a similar route in place, one that will look like `/categories/:category_id/products/new`. It can be difficult to tell what actual routes are auto-generated by the magic in `routes.rb`, that's why I suggest running `rake routes` in your terminal. BTW I'm writing out an actual answer at the moment with some more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined any route to handle your new product form's POST. You've defined the `new_product` path, but this arrangement is breaking Rails' conventions and you're not providing a work-around.

You could define another custom route, e.g. `post 'products', to: 'products#create', as: 'create_new_product'` and then set that in your form like `form_for @product, url: create_new_product_path do |f|`.

However, you should consider changing the structure so that product routes are not nested under categories. Think twice before breaking conventions this way.

Comment: This seems to function!!

Comment: Thanks. However, being new to rails, what is the danger of breaking convention like this?

Comment: I hesitated to change my routes so that Products are not nested under Categories, but the rest of my app has been built upon that, so I wanted to give it a shot

Comment: When you find yourself fighting against a pattern, take it as either a warning sign that the pattern you've chosen isn't a good fit, or a sign that you haven't fully internalized how the pattern should be used.

Comment: But that pattern simplifies a related JS implementation.. I'll check how I can un-nest. Thanks anyways a lot for your answer @Jeremy_Weathers, it works like this so far

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: I misread the intention, ignore this. Go with Jeremy Weather's answer.**

> Or is it impossible to Create a Child before assigning it to a Parent..?

With the way you have your relationships and validations set up: yes, it is. A Product requires a Category, through the `validates :category, presence: true`. And if you're on Rails 5+, the association will already be required by default (meaning that `validates` is actually redundant). Meaning if you try to create a Product without a Category, it will fail, and the Product will not be saved to the database.

With that constraint in place, here's what I recommend trying:

- Remove the custom `/products/new` route

  - remove `get 'products/new', to: 'products#new', as: 'new_product'`
- Add :new and :create routes to allow product creation nested under categories

  - Add `:create` and `:new`, to the `:only` array to the `resources :products` nested under `resources :categories`
- Move the file `views/products/new.html.erb` to `views/categories/products/new.html.erb` (creating a new `categories` directory in `views` if necessary).
- In that file, alter the `form_for` so that the form is POSTing to the nested :create route:

  - `form_for [@category, @product] do |f|`
- Visit the URL `/categories/[insert some Category ID here]/products/new`, filling out some data, and see if that works.

Your routes.rb should look like this:

```rb
resources :categories, only: [:index, :show, :new, :edit] do
  resources :products, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create, :edit]
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed a step, to edit the `form_for`. Editing my answer now.

Comment: Answer has been edited to include missing step(s), try that.

Comment: I tried it, however the link /categories/2/products/new brings me to views/products/new.html.erb and not to views/categories/products/new.html.erb

Comment: And no routes exist for categories/products/new

Comment: Sorry, I think I misread your original intent. Going back and reading the question, I see you're trying to create a Product with a `category_id` chosen from a dropdown. My mistake, I've been leading you down a different path. I got confused by how you already had some nested routes in place. I'd suggest you go with Jeremy Weather's answer. As he says, it isn't exactly Rails convention, but I think in your use case it makes sense.